# Viewport scale below 1 started to effect Adsense vignette ads

Tags: ads, viewport, adsense, vignette

A couple of days ago something's changed and now on every mobile phone, on every website with the viewport scale attribute set below 1 (which is most commonly) the Adsense vignette ads became cut and non fullscreen.

The only way to make vignette ads display correctly is to set "initial-scale=1" like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

But it makes impossible to change the website's scale on mobile phones.
Found no info on this issue.
If anyone has any ideas how to deal with it - please tell.
Thank you!